# RxJava 2 and working with Realm on the IO thread

Tags: caching, realm, repository-pattern, rx-java2

I am creating a method inside DataManager that first downloads data from cache, then requests data from server API, saves the result and sends given from network data to a presenter (in MVP).

The problem is that working with Realm happens on UI thread when I would like to make it on a background one. I found some articles about realm support of first RxJava but we are are using the second version that has another API, so these Realm methods do not help us (toObservable()).

How to resolve the issue?

Moreover, as I see it, all other methods are processed on IO thread and only Realm works on the Ui regardless of the fact that I put `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. Why it happens?

```
@Override
public Observable<ChatsRepoAnswerModel> getChats() {
    return getChatsFromCache(STATUS_OK)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .mergeWith(
                    getChatsService()
                            .getChats()
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .map(ChatResponseModel::getResult)
                            .flatMap(mChatsMapper::transformAll)
                            .doOnNext(this::saveChats)
                            .doOnNext(Collections::sort)                            
                            .onErrorResumeNext(getChatsFromCache(STATUS_ERROR))                               
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}


private void saveChats(List<ChatDataModel> realmObjects) {        
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(realm -> {
        realm.insertOrUpdate(realmObjects);
    });
}

private Observable<ChatsRepoAnswerModel> getChatsFromCache(int aStatus) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<ChatDataModel> chats = realm.where(ChatDataModel.class).findAll();
    return processChatResponse(realm.copyFromRealm(chats), aStatus);
}
```

Comment: Well you're getting all this trouble because you're supposed to be observing the observable data set provided by Realm; instead of [sending random "network data" around all over the place, and attempting to detach and eagerly copying out all elements from your reactive zero-copy lazy-evaluation-driven database](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/all-queries-off-the-ui-thread-using-detached-objects-how-to-professionally-misuse-realm-and-56683dbdeaf9).

Comment: Can you add some describing links, please?  Why I can use other methods when subscribeOn additional thread and this does not work with Realm?

Comment: Because you're trying to read on a background thread from your UI-thread-bound Realm instance. But I added an article about this stuff, maybe it helps

Comment: btw you're not closing your Realm instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well while I consider this to be a complete disregard for the zero-copy design of what Realm is trying to give you:

- unidirectional data-flow from the **auto-updating** and **reactive** data set provided by Realm in the form of `RealmResults` (meaning you are notified when the data set changes)
- **lazy-evaluation**, only elements accessed at a time are read, `RealmResults` is just a "cursor", and `RealmObject`s read data only when accessors are called
- **consistency**: all managed RealmProxies point to the same object, so you don't have "out of date" data anywhere (well, apart from non-autoupdating background threads that get retained, but that's generally a user error)

---

It's funny because `realm.copyFromRealm()` creates unmanaged objects which generally don't have either of those properties:

- no longer auto-updates
- eagerly evaluate the entire data set and copies all data to the fields
- as a result, not necessarily up to date in all places where used

---

Anyways, the solution to creating detached RealmObjects on the background thread is by opening the instance on that thread, copying the dataset, and closing the instance.

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> { // <-- defer to whatever thread you're running it on
        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            return realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Cat.class).findAll());
        } // <-- auto-close
    })
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.whatever());
```

Generally it's easier to just use Realm as intended, though, especially with larger data sets. Copying only really makes sense if you still preserve auto-updating, by running the Realm on a background looper thread (HandlerThread).